# How do I declare an instance of my class?

Tags: c++, function, instance

I have a Parser.h, Parser.cpp file with functions in it
the constructor is

```
Parser::Parser(string filename){....}
```

Now i want to use my parser in my functions.cpp file, where i made sure to

```
#include "Parser.h"
```

In my function i want to use the parser how do i make a new instance of it, this is what i have but i get syntax erorrs.

```
Parser::Parser parser("filename.txt");
```

sorry guys, i should have made sure i copied my code correctly, i dont have quotation mistakes, nor did i forget to inlude parser.h

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't your filename be "filename.txt" instead of 'filename.txt', which would be considered a character.  Perhaps you can show your debug code?

Comment: For people's information, there were apparently as least two edits to this question that corrected typos in the code copying, done fast enough to not be noted as edits to the question (yes, that works ehre).  Comments and answers that reference errors not found above relate to the earlier versions.

Comment: It seems like the chosen answer has been edited into the question... so was that the problem? Or have we just had a nice typo-fixing session? Confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include "functions.h"
```

Your header file name is `Parser.h`, not `functions.h`.

So do this:

```
#include "Parser.h"
```

Then this:

```
Parser parser("filename.txt"); //not Parser::Parser parser('filename.txt');
```

Use double-quotes, not single-quotes for string literals such as `"filename.txt"`

Comment: that was it, ill accept your answer in 8 minutes, i have a few other syntax i cant get right, c++ is new to me

Comment: @user570098:  When you're asking why you're having problems, typos are bad.  When it's a syntax error, typos are really, really bad.  ALWAYS cut and paste in situations like that.  You had, apparently, three distinct errors in the original version, and some people addressed the ones that were typos.

Answer (score 6):

(If you `#include`d `Parser.h`) you only need

```
Parser parser("filename.txt");
```

`Parser::Parser` marks the definition of the constructor method of the class `Parser`. However, the constructor can (and need) not be called directly - you invoke it implicitly by defining an instance of `Parser` like above.

Note that the filename should be in double quotes (single quotes denote single characters, double quotes are for text strings).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Parser::Parser parser("filename.txt");
```

Single quotes are for single characters not strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parser parser("filename.txt");
```